# Oozie stack trace for Spark Jobs - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, oozie

I am using Spark streaming jobs written in Java. They are launched using Oozie workflow. The jobs are working fine, however, whenever they are killed, we have set an email alert that sends email to our team. The problem is that we only see

```
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], exit code [1]
```

Whenever there is an exception, this is how I deal with it:

```
String outputFile = System.getProperty("oozie.action.output.properties");

String exception = Arrays.stream(ex.getStackTrace())
                .map(st -> st.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t"));

Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("stack-trace", exception);

try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            properties.store(out, "");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't store job output", ioe);
        }

// throw whatever exception there was
throw ex;
```

In my main class, whenever catch block is called, I am exiting like this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

because I read somewhere that if you exit with 1 code, then captureOutput doesn't work properly

This is how my workflow looks like:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="${name}"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to="startSparkConsumer"/>

    <!-- if cannot restart, try to just start it anyway -->
    <action name="startSparkConsumer">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${wf:conf("job.tracker")}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${wf:conf("name.node")}</name-node>
            <exec>${wf:conf("name.node")}${wf:conf("start.spark.script")}</exec>
            <argument>${environment}</argument>
            <argument>${wf:conf("name.node")}${wf:conf("jar")}</argument>
            <file>${wf:conf("name.node")}${wf:conf("start.spark.script")}</file>
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="failEmail"/>
    </action>

    <action name="failEmail">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
            <to>${wf:conf("email")}</to>
            <subject>Status of ${wf:conf("environment")} CLICKS workflow ${wf:id()}</subject>
            <body>
                The ${wf:conf("environment")} CLICKS workflow ${wf:id()} had issues and was killed. The error message is: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}
                Stack trace: ${wf:actionData(wf:lastErrorNode())["stack-trace"]}
            </body>
        </email>
        <ok to="fail"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>CLICK Workflow failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

This variable `${wf:actionData(wf:lastErrorNode())["stack-trace"]}` comes out to be empty. I don't know why is that, it should have the stack trace

Comment: 1. Check the yarn log of startSparkConsumer. Somewhere in there is a section telling you exactly what was captured. 

2. does explicitly giving the action name work? ```${wf:actionData('startSparkConsumer')['stack-trace']}```

Comment: @grantler I can find my log file, but there are so many of them on different machines that I can't find the file which has the exact exception in it
2. I tried this, but it didn't work either

Comment: Your Oozie job info will give you an external id that looks like ```job_1559111389094_8102```. Use this to run ```yarn logs -applicationId application_1559111389094_8102 > out.txt``` then run ```grep -n "capturing output data" out.txt``` and go to that line in the file to check if you are actually capturing anything. I think any shell error will also show up somewhere in that file.

Comment: @grantler Every time I try doing that, it gives me "either aggregation is not enabled or it's not completed". And I can see that on Cloudera, I have enabled this property